# Updating Pygame Score text

Tags: python, pygame

I have checked other answers for this problem but mine is a little bit different.

In my code below the score updates when I click on wrong answer but then it changes back to it's initial value, that is confusing me I checked the code and I feel like it is fine but I know that I am missing something or doing something wrong. Please kindly let me know where I am doing wrong. Below is my code.

```
#GAME SCREEN
def game_screen():

    player_score = 25
    timer = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    start = True
    while start :
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        seconds = (pygame.time.get_ticks()- timer)/1000

        main_font = pygame.font.Font("ArialRounded.TTF", 22)
        sub_font = pygame.font.Font("ArialRounded.TTF", 22)
        timer_font = sub_font.render(str(seconds), True, SEABLUE)
        question_font = main_font.render("Question:", True, SEABLUE)

        star_img = pygame.image.load("starscore.png")
        menu_screen_img = pygame.image.load("quizzappbackgroundscreen.png")
        blureffect_img = pygame.image.load("blureffect.png")
        onoff_button_img = pygame.image.load("onoffbutton.png")
        knobone_img = pygame.image.load("knob_a.png")
        knobtwo_img = pygame.image.load("knob_a.png")

        knobrect_a = knobone_img.get_rect(center=(97.5,647.5))
        knobrect_b = knobtwo_img.get_rect(center=(514.5,647.5))
        mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if knobrect_a.collidepoint(mpos):
            knobone_img = pygame.image.load("knob_b.png")
            if click[0] == 1:
                knobone_img = pygame.image.load("rotatedknob_a.png")
                click_sound.set_volume(0.3)
                click_sound.play()

        if knobrect_b.collidepoint(mpos):
            knobtwo_img = pygame.image.load("knob_b.png")
            if click[0] == 1:
                knobtwo_img = pygame.image.load("rotatedknob_a.png")
                click_sound.set_volume(0.3)
                click_sound.play()

        screen.blit(menu_screen_img, [0,0])
        screen.blit(star_img, [50,47])
        screen.blit(timer_font, [485,55])
        screen.blit(question_font, [50,95])
        question1(player_score)
        screen.blit(blureffect_img, [0,0])
        screen.blit(onoff_button_img, [25,726])
        screen.blit(knobone_img, [50,599])
        screen.blit(knobtwo_img, [465,599])

        pygame.display.update()

#QUESTIONS FUNCTIONS

def question1(player_score):

    main_font = pygame.font.Font("ArialRounded.TTF", 20)
    question_font = main_font.render("Are the points G, C, A, and Y coplanar?", True, SEABLUE)
    option1_font = main_font.render("- Yes", True, SEABLUE)
    option2_font = main_font.render("- No", True, SEABLUE)
    question_img1 = pygame.image.load("question1img.png")

    option1rect = option1_font.get_rect(center=(93.5,402))
    option2rect = option2_font.get_rect(center=(89.5,452))
    mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if option1rect.collidepoint(mpos):
        option1_font = main_font.render("- Yes", True, DSEABLUE)
        if click[0] == 1:
            print("Right Answer")
            #right_answers += 1
            print(right_answers)

    if option2rect.collidepoint(mpos):
        option2_font = main_font.render("- No", True, DSEABLUE)
        if click[0] == 1:
            print("Wrong Answer")
            player_score -=1


    screen.blit(question_font,[60,130])
    screen.blit(question_img1,[150,170])    
    screen.blit(option1_font, [70, 390])
    screen.blit(option2_font, [70, 430])
    draw_score(player_score)

#DRAW SCORE TEXT
def draw_score(player_score):

    font = pygame.font.Font("ArialRounded.TTF", 22)
    text = font.render("x" + str(player_score), True, SEABLUE)
    screen.blit(text, [85,55])
```

Comment: You are passing the player_score to functions and updating it locally. You may use it as a global variable which will make the score update permanent.

Comment: I did tried with defining the player_score globally but it was still doing the same thing.Right now it changes as soon as I click but it changes to initial value and on blitting it also changes on click but revert back to initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a variable from one function to another function and changing it there does not update it in the original function. Since you are passing `player_score` from `game_screen()` to `question1()`, update it in `question1()` and then call `draw_score()` with this updated value, you see the change for a moment, but `player_score` value doesn't get updated in your source function `game_screen()`, so in next call you again pass the original value and not the updated one.

One solution is to use global variable, but [global variables are not recommended.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

You could try something like this (I am describing an idea instead of updating your code):

```
def game_screen():

    player_score = 25    # your start score.

    while True:
        # receive question score here, update player's score and display it.
        question_score = question1()
        player_score += question_score
        draw_score(player_score)

def question1():

    # return question score from here regardless of player's current score.
    if correct_answer:
        return 1     # or return your value for correct answer
    else:
        return -1    # or return your value for incorrect answer

def draw_score(score):

    # your draw logic here.
```

Comment: Getting an error saying unsupported operand type on +=

Comment: The other thing is that this is just 1 question I will have more than 1 questions.

Comment: Ok, the idea here is not to update the player score in individual question function, but in the original game function. It doesn't matter how many questions do you have.